# Alternating current radiates?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current, maxwell-equations

Does a wire carrying alternating current release electromagnetic radiation in accordance with Maxwell's equations?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: It's called an antenna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. This is how radio antennas function.